# How to get time stamp of closest keyframe before a given timestamp with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, keyframe, ffprobe

To seek to position and get the closest frame I was using

```
ffprobe -i /path/to.mp3 -show_frames -show_entries frame=pkt_pos -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -hide_banner -loglevel panic -read_intervals $seconds%+#1
```

where I specify the start position as:

```
'-read_intervals', seconds + '%+#1', //Read only 1 packet after seeking to position 01:23
```

With latest `ffprobe`version

```
$ ffprobe --version
ffprobe version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
```

it does not work anymore, and I get

```
N/A
```

hence the "first", while if I remove the `$seconds%+#1` I get all

```
ffprobe -i /path/to.mp3 -show_frames -show_entries frame=pkt_pos -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -hide_banner -loglevel panic -read_intervals 20
N/A
1029888
1030306
1030724
1031142
1031560
1031978
1032396
1032814
1033232
1033650
1034068
1034486
1034904
...
```

How to retrieve the closest frame then not using the `read_intervals $seconds%+#1` but `read_intervals $seconds` only?